# Can I create a button that inherits the function of a navigation controller's back button?

Tags: swift3, uinavigationcontroller

Just learning about `UINavigationController` and I'm wondering, can I create a `UIButton` (for example, on the bottom left of the screen) that inherits the same function of the `UINavigationController`s back button?

Answer (score 0):

To do just make an IBOutlet action for the button which should look like this`@IBAction func signup(_ sender: UIButton) { // Code goes here }` then inside that function add this line of code `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`, so in the end your function should look like this `@IBAction func signup(_ sender: UIButton) { self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) }`. Hope this helped

Comment: I've written the IBOutlet action exactly as you said and it's not working..